# Highlight anchor element

Tags: html, css

I have the following three items displayed side by side:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1 style="line-height:0">Title</h1>
        <ul style="float: right; list-style-type: none;">
    <li><a href="http://test1.com">T1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://test2.com">T2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">T3</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I want to highlight the item once the user clicked on it (eg. T1). Something similar to how stackoverflow has the blocks like Questions, Tags, Users etc.

Comment: http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-glow ?

Comment: You need JavaScript, or server-side, script to implement this. What options are you willing, or able, to consider in that regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

```js
// Start up jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $('a.nav').removeClass('current_page');
    
    // Do an ajax call instead
    $('#response').html($(this).attr("href"));

    $(this).addClass('current_page');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
}
div#wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
}
.current_page {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#response {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a> |
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a> |
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a> |
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.myspace.com">Myspace</a> |
  <a class="nav" href="http://www.craigslist.com">Craigslist</a>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Response:</p>

  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

So basically, it pushes a class `.current_page` to the activated anchor tag which imprints that MEMORY ID in the DOM. You would then implement an ajax call to inject content within the page.